# Edit widget from plugin in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, widget, wordpress-shortcode

Is there a way to put the button on the same line as the selectors? I am using YMM Search plugin, any help will be appreciated. Also I'd like to change the colors of the selector to a darker one...

[image]

. . . . . . . . . . . .